# How much pressure would the raptor engines experience when Starship does an atmosphere entry burn at Mars?

Tags: spacex, mars, spacex-starship, specific-impulse, raptor

The Starship second stage has 3 sea level engines and 3 vacuum engines.

When doing the atmosphere entry burn to mars, how many Bars will the raptor engines experience?

I'm thinking that because of the high speed of entry, the resulting shock wave might increase the local pressure near the opening of the nozzle of the sea level engines, affecting (and possibly improving) their efficiency and/or resistance to flow separation.

[image]

Comment: I've adjusted your wording slightly, adding a few more "space words". Please feel free to adjust or edit further.